# Views charts pager doesn't match parent

Tags: views, paging, charts

I have a view with a table that has a pager to show 5 items at a time:

```
Items to display:Display a specified number of items | 5 items
```

In another display I have a chart that is attached to the table. How can I set the view so that the chart display the same content that is in the table? There is the `Inherit pager` option that I set to `Yes` but the chart always show the firts 5 items and not the 5 items showed in the table.

You can see in the image below that the chart is in fact limited to 5 (as the table) but the dates (x-axis) don't match.

[image]

Am I missing something here? Or is this a limitation?

Comment: Which charting module is this question about? Also the "Charts" module?

Comment: Yes - https://www.drupal.org/project/charts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another solution for this problem but after trying many things I noticed that one solution is to disable the sorting of the "Run Date and Time" field. This way, the table is always sorted in the same way for that field but the pager is respected.